# Referencing a Value

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I want to reference a alue in a header file to use in my cpp file.  The value name of the value is currentaddress.  Here is the code...

```
HOSTENT *pHostEnt2;
int  **ppaddr2;
SOCKADDR_IN sockAddr2;
char* addr2;
pHostEnt2 = gethostbyname(NewLogURL.c_str());
ppaddr2 = (int**)pHostEnt2->h_addr_list;
sockAddr2.sin_addr.s_addr = **ppaddr2;
addr2 = inet_ntoa(sockAddr2.sin_addr);
printf("\n   Current Website IP:%s", addr2);
```

I tried this...

```
char getcurradd(char addr2)
{
return addr2;
}
```

But it say that I have the wrong value for the function.  Any help is appreciated. Thnak you.
I would call it like this...

```
 char CA = getcurradd(*addr2);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  How do those two fragments of code relate to one another?  Why does the second fragment do nothing but return its own argument?

Comment: OK, The above code is in a header file.  I just need to pass or get the value of currentaddress from the header file to the cpp file.  I hope this is clearer.

Comment: You can't do that.  As written, currentaddress is a local variable, only defined within a particular function.  There's no way to get at the value of a local variable from outside the function in which it is defined.  Instead, make currentaddress a global variable.

Comment: (To make currentaddress a global variable, declare it outside of any function.)

Comment: OK so I made it a global variable and did this in the header file.  See the question on what I did in the header file and the cpp file to call it.

Comment: OK this was really simple! I just placed it as a global variable as you suggested and walla! I can now access it.  Thank you so very much!  Put it in a solution so that I may give you credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really simple! I just placed it as a global variable and I now can access it.